# How to determine Integraton limits?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I'm pretty confused by how we should determine Integration limits.

> $f_p(x)=x^3-px^2$
>
> $V$ is the surface area enclosed by the graph of $f_2$ and the x-axis.
>
> $V$ is  revolved    around  the x-axis. 
>   Analytically    calculate   the volume  of  the resulting solid of  revolution

I know the formula for figuring out the volume of revolutions around the $x$-achse is to just integrate $\pi(f(x)^2$, but I would still need to figure out the integration limits and I'm really lost on how to do that.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Where does $f_2$ cross the $x-$axis?

Comment: But why would the x intercept be the point of upper limit? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: you have been asked to find the region enclosed by the curve and the x-axis.

Comment: So if the graph intercepts the x achse twice? How would I know which one is meant?

Comment: Both of them! One is the lower limit, and one is the upper limit.

Comment: Oh so lets say it happens 3 times I would go from point 1 to point 2, and then point 2 to 3?

Comment: Then the question would be less clearly posed.  And you would need more information regarding your objectives.

Comment: I see, thanks Doug! That explains it :). You should turn this into an answer, I feel like this is pretty satisfying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the integration limits, you must find the places where $f_2 (x)$ and the $x$-axis cross. You do this by setting
$$x^3 - 2x^2 = 0$$
$$x^2 (x-2) = 0$$
$$x = 0, 2$$
Because $f_2 (x) \le 0$ for $x \in [0, 2]$, $V$ would be equal to the opposite of the integral of $f_2 (x)$.
$$V = -\int_{0}^{2} f_2 (x)~ {\rm d}x = -\int_{0}^{2} \left(x^3 - 2x^2\right) {\rm d}x$$
I hope this is of help!